# How to model a medium-sized data set with multiple types as a class

Tags: java, validation, oop, design-patterns

### Problem

I don't know the best way to model my data.  I'm worried my current approach has gotten overly complex, and I want to correct it now before I base any more code off it.

### Data to be Modeled

I have data sets that consist of 50+ different data items.  Each item consists of:

- a unique identifier `int`
- a label `String`.
- validation criteria (min, max, legal characters, etc...).
- a value `Float`, `Long`, `Integer`, `String`, or `Date`.

The label and validation criteria for each item *is the same in every data set*.  *Only the values are dynamic.* Order is not important.

### Needed Usage Examples

Add data to the data set

```
dataSet.put(itemIdentifier, value);
```

Traverse and validate all non-null values in the data set

```
for (DataItem item : dataSet.values()) {
    boolean valid = item.validate();
    if (valid) {...}
}
```

Show the specified items in the given data sets

```
public void displayData(List<DataSet> dataSets, int... itemsIdentifiers) {...}
```

### Implementation Attempt

My current implementation has an abstract `Key` class as the "key" to a map.  Each type subclasses for its own validation needs.  Then, inside the `DataSet` class, I have `public static` keys for each item.

```
abstract public class Key {
    public int mId;
    public String mLabel;

    public Key(int id, String label) {...}
    abstract public boolean validate(Object Value);
}

public class FloatKey extends Key {
    private int mMin, mMax;

    public Key(int id, String label, int min, int max) {...}
    public boolean validate(Object Value) {...}
}

// one for each type
...

public class DataSet {
    public static Key ITEM_A = new FloatKey(1, "item A", 0, 100);
    public static Key ITEM_B = new DateKey(2, "item B", "January 1, 1990");
    // ~50 more of these

    private Map<Key, Object> mMap;

    public void put(int itemId, Object value) {...}
    public Set<Object> values() {...};
    ...
}
```

I don't like that when I pull values out of `DataSet`, I need to hold onto the value AND the key so I can do things like `DataSet.ITEM_A.validate(someFloat)`.  I also find myself using `instanceof` and casting frequently when I traverse objects in a set because I need to call subclass-only methods in some situations.

---

### Edits for further clarification

- Data items and their validation criteria will require occasional changes and so maintenance should be relatively easy / painless.
- Although I could use the `Key` objects themselves as keys into the map, I will sometimes need to put these keys in a `Bundle` (part of the android API).  I would rather use the `label` or `id` (in case labels are the same) to avoid making my `Key` class `Parcelable`.

Comment: I'll answer this. Sooner or later.

Comment: I think this belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: Why is it requiring instanceOf? Can you give an example?

Comment: @KaushikGuha When I retrieve objects from `DataSet`, I have been using `instanceof` to check the type, then casting, and then performing different actions depending upon the type.  This is especially true in my display code.  I'm also type-checking every value added to the array in the put method.  So some of it is probably me not trusting my contracts, and some of it is necessary for specific display code.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach:
Create this interface:

```
interface Validable {
    boolean isValid();
}
```

Then, all data items inherit the following class and implicitly the interface ::

```
abstract class DataItem implements Validable {

    public DataItem(int id, String label, int min, int max) {
    }
}
```

Configure each specific instance of DataItem via constructor parameters, passing the common and the distinct values:

```
class FloatItem extends DataItem {

    public FloatItem(int id, String label, int min, int max, Float value) {
        super(id, label, min, max);
        // set the Float value here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid() {
        // validate here
        return true;
    }
}

class DateItem extends DataItem {

    public DateItem(int id, String label, int min, int max, Date value) {
        super(id, label, min, max);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid() {
        // validate here
        return true;
    }
}
```

The client code would assemble the objects like this::

```
List<Validable> items = Lists.<Validable>newArrayList(new FloatItem(0, "", 0, 0, Float.NaN),
            new DateItem(0, "", 0, 0, new Date()));
```

(note the usage of Google Guava)

Calling code only needs to do this::

```
for (Validable validable : items) {
    System.out.println(validable.isValid());
}
```

Please note that this approach requires you to first create 'target' objects, and then ask the question if they are valid. In other words, you are passing the valid-able parameters via constructor and then, you ask the object if it is valid. The object itself will answer the question using the validation criteria inside it...
I hope I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood my problem correctly. I'll try to give a more concrete example. Let's say one of the data item is a Float representing temperature, and has some valid range of values, let's say 0 to 500. Every data set will have a float with the label="temperature", min=0, max=500. My problem is that I'd like to only store these things parameters once, and relate them to the respective value in every data set. Your solution above would require re-supplying the same validation criteria for each `DataItem` every time a new `DataSet` is created. Let me know if that is more clear

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are worried about passing the 'basic' parameters to each instance. `new FloatItem(0, "", 0, 0, Float.NaN)`. Why not then making `id`, `label`, `min`, `max` sensible defaults in each class? Then the constructor would become `new FloatItem(Float value)`. If you still think you would need to override the basic params in the future, solutions exist...

Comment: One of my key needs is that each of these items has it's own valid range.  Adding sensible defaults may be a good addition, but it does not help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your goals with the design, so maybe not all of this is correct or directly useful to you, but it's some ideas to play with.

First I'd point out that there are lots of fields in the code you've shown that should be marked `final`. For example, `Key.mId`, `Key.mLabel`, `FloatKey.mMin`, `FloatKey.mMax`, all the `DataSet.ITEM_X`, and `DataSet.mMap`. Marking them `final` (1) conveys the intended behavior better, (2) prevents accidents where something like a Key's `mId` changes, and (3) might have marginal performance benefits.

I wonder why you need the numeric ID for each key/field? If they're required for interfacing with some external application or storage format which already defines those IDs, that makes sense, but if it's only for internal things like this method:

```
public void displayData(List<DataSet> dataSets, int... itemsIdentifiers) {...}
```

then that could be more meaningfully implemented using a list of String labels or Key objects, instead of the numeric IDs. Likewise, `DataSet.put` could possibly use the Key or label instead of the ID.

> I find myself using instanceof and casting frequently when I traverse objects in a set

Making `Key` generic can eliminate some casts. (Well, they will still be present in the bytecode, but not in the source because the compiler will take care of it.) E.g.,

```
abstract public class Key<T> {
    ...
    abstract public boolean validate(T Value);
}

public class FloatKey extends Key<Float> {
    ...
    public boolean validate(Float value) { ... }
}
```

In the `validate` method, you thus avoid the need to cast `value`.

Also, I'm guessing you currently have a method on class `DataSet` like this:

```
public Object get(int itemId) { ... }
```

If you use the Key instead of numeric ID to retrieve values, and make the method generic, you'll often be able to avoid the need for callers to cast the return value (though the cast is still present inside the `get` method):

```
public <T> T get(Key<T> key) { ... }
```

> I don't like that when I pull values out of DataSet, I need to hold onto the value AND the key so I can do things like `DataSet.ITEM_A.validate(someFloat)`.

You could make a class for the value instead of the key. E.g.,

```
abstract public class Value<T> {
    public final int id;
    public final String label;

    protected Value(int id, String label) {
        this.id = id;
        this.label = label;
    }

    abstract public T get();
    abstract public void set(T value);
}

public class FloatValue extends Value<Float> {
    private final float min, max;
    private float value;

    public FloatValue(int id, String label, float min, float max, float value) {
        super(id, label);
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        set(value);
    }

    public Float get() { return value; }

    public void set(Float value) {
        if (value < min | value > max) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class DataSet {
    public final FloatValue itemA = new FloatValue(1, "item A", 0, 100, 0);
    ...

}
```

That solves the stated problem, and also eliminates the map lookup previously required on every get/set of a value. However it has the side effect of duplicating the storage for the labels and numeric IDs, as the Value classes are not static fields any more.

In this scenario, to access DataSet values by label (or ID?), you can use reflection to build a map. In class DataSet:

```
private final Map<String, Value<?>> labelMap = new HashMap<>();
{
    for (Field f : DataSet.class.getFields()) {
        if (Value.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType())) {
            Value<?> v;
            try {
                v = (Value<?>)f.get(this);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e); // shouldn't happen
            }
            labelMap.put(v.label, v);
        }
    }
}
```

There's a subtlety here: if you subclass DataSet to represent different types of data, then the Value fields of the subclasses will not have been initialized yet at the time DataSet's initializer builds the map. So if you create subclasses of DataSet, you might need a protected `init()` method to be called from subclass constructors, to tell it to (re)build the map, which is a bit ugly but it would work.

You can re-use this map to provide convenient iteration of a DataSet's values:

```
public Collection<Value<?>> values() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(labelMap.values());
}
```

A final idea: if you're using reflection anyway, it might be possible to use ordinary fields for the values, with [annotation interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html) to implement their behavior.

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class DataSet {
    @Label("item A") @ValidateFloat(min=0, max=100) public float itemA;
    @Label("item B") public String itemB;

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface Label {
        String value();
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static @interface ValidateFloat {
        float min();
        float max();
    }

    public final class Value {
        public final String label;
        private final Field field;

        protected Value(String label, Field field) {
            this.label = label;
            this.field = field;
        }

        public Object get() {
            try {
                return field.get(DataSet.this);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e); // shouldn't happen
            }
        }

        public void set(Object value) {
            try {
                field.set(DataSet.this, value);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new AssertionError(e); // shouldn't happen
            }
        }

        public void validate() {
            Object value = get();

            // Test for presence of each validation rule and implement its logic.
            // Ugly but not sure how best to improve this...

            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(ValidateFloat.class)) {
                float floatValue = (float)value;
                ValidateFloat rule = field.getAnnotation(ValidateFloat.class);
                if (floatValue < rule.min() || floatValue > rule.max()) {
                    //throw new Whatever();
                }
            }

            //if (field.isAnnotationPresent(...)) {
            //  ...
            //}
        }
    }

    private final Map<String, Value> labelMap = new HashMap<>();
    {
        for (Field f : DataSet.class.getFields()) {
            if (f.isAnnotationPresent(Label.class)) {
                Value value = new Value(f.getAnnotation(Label.class).value(), f);
                labelMap.put(value.label, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public Collection<Value> values() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(labelMap.values());
    }
}
```

This approach has different tradeoffs. Code that knows exactly what field it wants can access it directly. E.g., `dataSet.itemA` instead of `dataSet.get(DataSet.ITEM_A)`. Code that needs to iterate multiple fields does so via the Value wrapper (*would `Property` be a better class name? Or `Item`?*), which encapsulates the ugliness of the field reflection code.

I also put the validation logic into the annotations. If there are lots of fields with very simple numeric limits, that works well. If it's too complex for that you'd be better off with a `DataSet.validate` method that accesses the fields directly. E.g,

```
public void validate() {
    if (itemC < 10 || itemC > itemD) ...
}
```

Okay, one more idea:

```
public class DataSet {
    public float itemA;
    public String itemB;


    public static abstract class Value<T> {
        public final String label;

        protected Value(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        public abstract T get();
        public abstract void set(T value);
    }


    public Value<?>[] values() {
        return new Value[] {
            new Value<Float>("itemA") {
                public Float get() {
                    return itemA;
                }

                public void set(Float value) {
                    itemA = value;
                }
            },

            new Value<String>("itemB") {
                public String get() {
                    return itemB;
                }

                public void set(String value) {
                    itemB = value;
                }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

This is simple (no annotations or reflection) but it's repetitive. Since you have "50+" fields, the repetitiveness is probably not ideal as it's easy when copy-pasting to slip up at some point, forgetting to replace `itemX = value` with `itemY = value`, but if you only need to write it once it might be acceptable. Validation code could go either on the Value class or the DataSet class.

Comment: They should definitely be "final", thank you.  As far as the reason for an integer id, it's to avoid making the class `Parcelable` for android... which I didnt mention in my question.  As for the general approach you presented, I considered this approach, and rejected it for the exact reason you stated. It is very easy to make mistakes with so many fields. While it will not be very frequent, updates will need to be made to these fields occasionally. This approach makes that maintenance relatively difficult and error-prone.

Comment: I mean for the final idea you presented... I'm still taking in the advantages/disadvantages of the other ideas. Thanks for giving me so many ideas! It may be better to put them into separate answers to better fit the stackoverflow format.